# cotangent bundle splits as a product?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $M$ and $N$ be two Riemannian manifolds with Riemannian metrics $g$, $h$ respectively. We consider the product $M \times N$ with metric $g \oplus h$. By the metric we get an isomorphism of bundles $T(M \times N) = TM \times TN$.

My question is: is this also true for the cotangent bundle?

I.e. is $T^{*}(M \times N) = T^{*}M \times T^{*}N$?

I hope for a lot of answers and want to thank in advance.

Comment: Why would you need the metric for the isomorphism of the tangent bundles?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't require much to define a tangent space and then a cotangent space. Relatively speaking a Riemannian metric is a very strong instance of a metric, which [gives raise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotangent_space#Properties) to a natural isomorphism of the bundle and here follows the illustration of the construction:

If you think of $V=V^i\partial_i$ as your vectors and $g(V,W)=g_{ij}V^iW^j$, then

$$g(V,W)
=g_{ij}V^iW^j
=g_{ij}(g^{ik}\alpha_k)(g^{jl}\beta_l)
=g^{kl}\alpha^V_k\beta^W_l
=:G(\alpha^V,\beta^W),$$

where I used $g_{ij}g^{ik}=\delta^k_j$. 
So for each $V=V^i\partial_i$ you have a $\alpha^V=\alpha^V_i\text dx^i$ and for them a metric $G$. More abstractly speaking, you pull back the metric to $T^{*}(M \times N)$, thus making it a tangent space with a Riemannian metric too (with $T^{*}(M \times N)$ its cotangent space). Hence all such Riemann geometry statements for tangent bundles translate.

Btw. it's $\ TM \oplus TN$.

Comment: Re: your last statement, that's why I wrote my comment above. There is a canonical isomorphism $T(M\times N) = TM\times TN$ _as smooth manifolds_. A reference is Section 1.12 of Kolar-Michor-Slovak's _Natural Operations in Differential Geometry_. However, I am not quite sure what the OP meant by "isomorphism of bundles" since I am not sure what he intends the base manifold and bundle projection to be on $TM\times TN$.

Comment: @WillieWong: You can take an external direct sum of bundles.  If $E_j \to X_j, j=1,2$ are vector bundles and $p_i : X_1 \times X_2 \to X_i$ denotes the projection, then $E_1 \times E_2 \to X_1 \times X_2$ can be thought of as $p_1^* E_1 \oplus p_2^* E_2$.